# What is the difference between happens with and happens to

Tags: difference, usage

During a conversation between me and one of my friends, I was drunk and saying strange things.

- He said "it happens"

I replied

- It happens every time with me....

Which I guess means that in my case it happens every time.

And if I had said ***it happen to me every time***, then that would mean that it causes something to me I guess.

---

So, What is the difference between ***happens with*** and ***happens to***?

Answer (score 1):

Your paraphrase **in my case** for *with me* there is good.  *to me* means, as you say, that you have been affected by something.

Answer (score 1):

"Happens with" means everything that has to do with a subject (in this case you):

> What happens with me?

"Happens to" means everything that has to do with other situations among a subject (in this case you):

> What is happening to me?